# android studio Gradle issues sync

Tags: java, android

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:43.1.2.
Searched in the following locations:

- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/43.1.2/gradle-43.1.2.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/43.1.2/gradle-43.1.2.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/43.1.2/gradle-43.1.2.pom
- https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/build/gradle/43.1.2/gradle-43.1.2.pom
  Required by:
  project :
  Add google Maven repository and sync project
  Open File

Unknown host 'No such host is known (jitpack.i3o)'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle

I can't run my app.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLNjR.png)

Comment: what is your gradle versions..??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.